# Force HTTP on all pages except specific URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I have a situation where I need to force every single page in my site to redirect to HTTP except for two specific URLs which need to force redirect to HTTPS.

The two pages that need to redirect to HTTPS pages are:

*/microsoft-moc-on-demand-video-training/moc-registration-page/*

*/courses/register/*

The code I've been using in my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/courses/register/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/microsoft-moc-on-demand-video-training/moc-registration-page/
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(/courses/register/|/microsoft-moc-on-demand-video-training/moc-registration-page/)/ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working. The entire site does redirect to HTTP (so part of the code works), but those two exceptions (which should redirect to HTTPS) do not do that, they stay as HTTP links.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: DigitalSky. Did this answer help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you use a RewriteRule in .htaccess, it uses per-directory (relative) context, meaning that the *pattern* value should **not** include a leading slash. Your *pattern* also includes an extra trailing slash at the end which will cause problems. Try the following, which fixes those two items:

```
RewriteRule ^(courses/register/|microsoft-moc-on-demand-video-training/moc-registration-page/) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```